# Why is the throughput of a network so slow?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, nio

I just made two threads communicating in a simple client-server fashion. Here's the code for the sender:

```
    //Open and configure the socket   
    SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open();
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5050);
    channel.connect(address);
    channel.socket().setTcpNoDelay(true);
    channel.socket().setKeepAlive(false);
    int count = 0;
    OutputStream os = channel.socket().getOutputStream();
    int amount = 50;

    //Prepare a simple buffer to send.
    byte[] data = new byte[amount];
    Arrays.fill(data, (byte)1);

    double start = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Time it.

    //Send and print the throughput each 50000 tuples.
    while(true){
        count++;
        IOUtils.write(data, os);
        if(count % 50000==0){
            double totalsize = count;
            double end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double time = (end-start)/1000;
            System.out.println("Writer:"+(totalsize/time)/1000000+"Tuples/second");
        }
    }
```

And for the receiver:

```
    .....//Just accepting the channel.

    //After accepting the channel. Read the tuples.

    readC.socket().setTcpNoDelay(true);
    readC.socket().setKeepAlive(false);
    byte[] readbuf = new byte[50];
    InputStream is = readC.socket().getInputStream();
    double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true){
        IOUtils.read(is, readbuf);
    }
```

The output says that the average tuples per second is only 0.1 x 10^6, which means each tuple = 50 bytes, I could only get 5MB/s throughput.

Both threads run on local computer, so I assume the ideal throughput is far more larger than I got.

I also check the wireshark for the reason, and found, when I send one tuple, let's say, from port 71581 to port 5050. Then there will be a bunch of tcp packets sent, roughly 300 packets!!!!! AND, among those 300 packets, only 1 packet is really sending the data between 71581 to 5050.

For the other 299 packets, a weird thing is that the communications are between port 71581 and 71580 (Neighbor port). Any body could explain why it is doing such a stupid thing? Can I disable it?

Any suggestions, comments, and ideas would be very appreciated!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you!

Comment: What are the contents of the 299 other packets? What TCP flags do they have set?

Comment: Mostly, ACK, or PSH/ACK as shown by the wireshark

Comment: For the other 299 packets, all the psh/ack flagged packets have 10~100 bytes data field containing random content which is non-human readable.

Comment: Why are you setting TCP nodelay for bulk throughput?

Comment: I am not sure, I guess disabling Nagle's algorithm could be suitable for small packets?

Comment: Disabling Nagle's algorithm is appropriate for when you have small packets that are only being sent occasionally and you need to lower latency while still using TCP. Nagle's should be enabled for a bulk transfer such as this one where you are attempting to send data at a maximum throughput.

Comment: If the Wireshark data is relevant to this question it should be posted here, and as text, not as a picture. The main issue I can see is your tiny receive buffer size. If you're testing streaming throughout you need to test it realistically.

Comment: @hexafraction Why is it bulk transfer in my case? I send 50 bytes data in each loop, this is small.

Comment: @fTTTTT Yes, but you are sending that data in a tight loop, as fast as you can. Even though the individual pieces of data are small, TCP is a *stream-oriented* protocol, meaning that all the data is concatenated into a stream anyway, and then deserialized at the other end. The fact that you have Nagle's disabled causes massive amounts of overhead to be sent for each of those 50 bytes; this overhead is causing a slowdown. Turn Nagle's back on and see for yourself.